# Modification of biblatex APA style

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, apa-style

For my final thesis I need to use a slightly modified version of the APA style. Before I go into more detail, I would like to show you a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-comp,
bibstyle=apa]{biblatex}   
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ \addabbrvspace al\adddot}}

\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib} 
@book{XYZ2010, 
 author = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason and Christian Gammason}, 
 year = {2010}, 
 title = {{Ein Testbuch}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart}
}
@book{XYZ2011,
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason and Christian Gammason},
 year = {2011},
 title = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
@incollection{XYZ2012,
 title = {{Meine kleine Testdatei}},
 author = {Dirk Deltason},
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason and Christian Gammason},
 year = {2012},
 booktitle = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart}, 
}
@incollection{XYZ2013,
 title = {{Meine kleine Testdatei}},
 author = {Dirk Deltason},
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason},
 year = {2013},
 booktitle = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart}, 
}
@book{XYZ2014a, 
 author = {Phil Phison and Bertram Betason}, 
 year = {2014}, 
 title = {{Ein Testbuch}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
} 
@book{XYZ2014b, 
 author = {{Fictional Institution}}, 
 year = {2014}, 
 title = {{Ein Testbuch}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
@incollection{XYZ2014c,
 title = {{Meine kleine Testdatei}},
 author = {Dirk Deltason and Ezra Epsilonson},
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason},
 year = {2014},
 booktitle = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
\end{filecontents} 
\bibliography{literatur} 

\begin{document} 
\parencite{XYZ2010,XYZ2011,XYZ2012,XYZ2013,XYZ2014a,XYZ2014b,XYZ2014c}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

What I need to change is:

1. There should be a comma before "&" in case of 2 AND more than 2 authors/editors in the initial position of the bibliography entry.
2. In case the editors appear afterwards like in entry No. 3 and 4 in the MWE there should be only a comma before "&" in case there are more than 2 editors. No comma for only 2 editors here. Don't ask me why, I just have to do it like that!
3. APA normally prints a period between the authors/editors/institution and the year (in brackets). I am not allowed to insert a period there. How can I remove it? In the example, the period in entry No. 2 after "(Hrsg.)" would not be allowed.

I've inserted an image of the output. I used red to indicate what's wrong and green to show what's correct.

[image: Bibliography]

Edit info: I added some more examples to demonstrate the issues I am talking about.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Big thanks for adding an MWE from the start for your first question!

Comment: @Seb as I said below: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can merge them together for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are;

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-comp,
bibstyle=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ \addabbrvspace al\adddot}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@book{XYZ2010,
 author = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason and Christian Gammason},
 year = {2010},
 title = {{Ein Testbuch}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart}
}
@book{XYZ2011,
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason and Christian Gammason},
 year = {2011},
 title = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
@incollection{XYZ2012,
 title = {{Meine kleine Testdatei}},
 author = {Dirk Deltason},
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason and Christian Gammason},
 year = {2012},
 booktitle = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
@incollection{XYZ2013,
 title = {{Meine kleine Testdatei}},
 author = {Dirk Deltason},
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason},
 year = {2013},
 booktitle = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}

 \DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{\def\finalandcomma{\addcomma}}

\xpatchbibmacro{editorinauthpos}{%
       \clearname{editor}%
       \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
}{%
       \clearname{editor}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
}{}{}

\begin{document}

\parencite{XYZ2010,XYZ2011,XYZ2012,XYZ2013}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]