# Follow-up-question to modification of biblatex APA style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

For my final thesis I need to use a slightly modified version of the APA style. Before I go into more detail, I would like to show you a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-comp,
bibstyle=apa]{biblatex}   
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ \addabbrvspace al\adddot}}

\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib} 
@book{XYZ2010, 
 author = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason and Christian Gammason}, 
 year = {2010}, 
 title = {{Ein Testbuch}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart}
}
@book{XYZ2011,
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason and Christian Gammason},
 year = {2011},
 title = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
@incollection{XYZ2012,
 title = {{Meine kleine Testdatei}},
 author = {Dirk Deltason},
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason and Christian Gammason},
 year = {2012},
 booktitle = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart}, 
}
@incollection{XYZ2013,
 title = {{Meine kleine Testdatei}},
 author = {Dirk Deltason},
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason},
 year = {2013},
 booktitle = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart}, 
}
@book{XYZ2014a, 
 author = {Phil Phison and Bertram Betason}, 
 year = {2014}, 
 title = {{Ein Testbuch}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
} 
@book{XYZ2014b, 
 author = {{Fictional Institution}}, 
 year = {2014}, 
 title = {{Ein Testbuch}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
@incollection{XYZ2014c,
 title = {{Meine kleine Testdatei}},
 author = {Dirk Deltason and Ezra Epsilonson},
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason},
 year = {2014},
 booktitle = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
\end{filecontents} 
\bibliography{literatur} 

\begin{document} 
\parencite{XYZ2010,XYZ2011,XYZ2012,XYZ2013,XYZ2014a,XYZ2014b,XYZ2014c}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

What I need to change is:

1. There should be a comma before "&" in case of 2 AND more than 2 authors/editors in the initial position of the bibliography entry.
2. In case the editors appear afterwards like in entry No. 3 and 4 in the MWE there should be only a comma before "&" in case there are more than 2 editors. No comma for only 2 editors here. Don't ask me why, I just have to do it like that!
3. APA normally prints a period between the authors/editors/institution and the year (in brackets). I am not allowed to insert a period there. How can I remove it? In the example, the period in entry No. 2 after "(Hrsg.)" would not be allowed.

I've inserted an image of the output. I used red to indicate what's wrong and green to show what's correct.

[image: Bibliography]

See also [Modification of biblatex APA style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241308/modification-of-biblatex-apa-style).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code should satisfy your requirements:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-comp,
bibstyle=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ \addabbrvspace al\adddot}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@book{XYZ2010,
 author = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason and Christian Gammason},
 year = {2010},
 title = {{Ein Testbuch}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart}
}
@book{XYZ2011,
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason and Christian Gammason},
 year = {2011},
 title = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
@incollection{XYZ2012,
 title = {{Meine kleine Testdatei}},
 author = {Dirk Deltason},
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason and Christian Gammason},
 year = {2012},
 booktitle = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
@incollection{XYZ2013,
 title = {{Meine kleine Testdatei}},
 author = {Dirk Deltason},
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason},
 year = {2013},
 booktitle = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
@book{XYZ2014a,
 author = {Phil Phison and Bertram Betason},
 year = {2014},
 title = {{Ein Testbuch}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
@book{XYZ2014b,
 author = {{Fictional Institution}},
 year = {2014},
 title = {{Ein Testbuch}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
@incollection{XYZ2014c,
 title = {{Meine kleine Testdatei}},
 author = {Dirk Deltason and Ezra Epsilonson},
 editor = {Andrew Alphason and Bertram Betason},
 year = {2014},
 booktitle = {{Ein Sammelwerk}},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart},
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{literatur}

    \usepackage{xpatch}

     \DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{\def\finalandcomma{\addcomma}}

    \xpatchbibmacro{editorinauthpos}{%
           \clearname{editor}%
           \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
    }{%
           \clearname{editor}%
           \setunit{\addspace}%
    }{}{}
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
      {}
      {\finalandcomma\addspace\&\space}
         }}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifnameundef{author}
    {\usebibmacro{labeltitle}}
    {\printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printfield{nameaddon}%
     \ifnameundef{with}
       {}
       {\setunit{}\addspace\mkbibparens{\printtext{\bibstring{with}\addspace}%
        \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{with}}
        \setunit*{\addspace}}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}}

\xpretobibmacro{editor+trans}{\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}}


\begin{document}
\parencite{XYZ2010,XYZ2011,XYZ2012,XYZ2013,XYZ2014a,XYZ2014b,XYZ2014c}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]